# Program cannot reconnect to Firebird after abnormal termination

Tags: firebird, c++builder, firebird2.1

What can be done to prevent having to restart a PC after a program (C++Builder) terminated abnormaly without closing the database using firebird 2?

What I am looking for: I would like to be able to just restart the program without any other intervention. (I could have the user call a batch file executing some cleanup or add some lines of code to the program to disconnect everything.)

Comment: It would help to know what happens when you try to restar the app. Any error messages?

Comment: Which component you use for accessing firebird ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is firebird 2.1+, there are monitoring tables that show the active connections, and the sysdba can manually delete any left-over connnections.
If you look in your release notes, the syntax details should be there.